# Is it a good idea to use time instead of string CURRENT_DATE in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I decided to use time instead of string date in MySQL, but I want to know whether it is a good idea. For example I use:

```
1268557200
```

instead of:

```
Sun, 14 Mar 2010 09:00:00 GMT
```

Thanks.

Comment: would you store your integers in varchars and parse every time ?

Comment: No, I would store integers in int

Comment: thats the spirit :) mysql provides lots of optimization and utilities for the exact type you want to use. It would be so so so rare to have advantage by using the data types not the way they are meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course is it better a special type. The database is optimized for such types. E.g. your string there has very much chars the date types are internally ints or longs which just take 4 or 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

It generally makes the most sense to use the type that most closely represents the data you're trying to store. Which is to say, if your data is date-oriented, then use a date-oriented field. These are stored as numbers internally, which is categorically faster to access, store, sort, etc., than strings. The advantage is that you access (both in and out) as if they were strings, but they work and sort like numbers.

An important point is to not use date math in queries. Do the math (adding days, subtracting hours, etc.) in code *before* you compose the SQL. This allows you to take full advantage of indexes, query caching, etc. There are some optimizations that allow you to get away with leaving the date math in SQL, but it might not be obvious where the pitfalls are. So unless you know for certain that what you're doing is optimized, a good rule of thumb is to keep the calculations out of the SQL.